# Why am I getting 'ValueError: mismatch between column_names and columns coded by given terms' on what looks like a valid dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have created a pandas dataframe from a python dictionary, which as far as I can see looks valid but generates 'ValueError: mismatch between column_names and columns coded by given terms' when I try to run an ANOVA. A similarly constructed dataframe from different data has no such problem. What does this value error mean? From looking at design_info.py it suggests to me that the column count does not match the number of column headings, but I can't see anything wrong with the DF from examining the head, what am I missing?

```
data = {'PID': [..], 'Focus': [..], 'proportionGazeTime': [..], 'gazeFrequency': [..], 'avGazeTime': [..]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
aovrm = AnovaRM(df, 'proportionGazeTime', 'PID', within=['Focus'])
res = aovrm.fit()
```

For clarity [..] represent the list of values associated with each dict key.

print out of df.head():

```
  PID        Focus  proportionGazeTime  gazeFrequency  avGazeTime  
0   1  RightArrowS            0.013770      16.408938    0.057735  
1   1       PlaneS            0.499794       2.586971    0.386553  
2   1   AltimeterS            0.012714      16.125863    0.059580  
3   1    Mini-MapS            0.033169       9.209054    0.105693  
4   1     nothingS            0.103445       4.368551    0.224747
```

I have looked at the df.columns.values and that gives me the headings I would expect and has length of 5 as it should.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works

```
from statsmodels.stats.anova import AnovaRM # 0.9.0
import pandas as pd # 0.24.2

data = {'PID': [1,1,1,1], 'Focus': ['R','P','A','M'], 'proportionGazeTime': [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4], 'gazeFrequency': [16,2,9,4], 'avGazeTime': [7,8,9,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.head()
aovrm = AnovaRM(df, 'proportionGazeTime', 'PID', within=['Focus'])

res = aovrm.fit()
```

Maybe we have different versions ?